# Finding the number paths in a grid where the paths must pass through a certain point

Tags: combinatorics

[image: Problem]

Hello,

I'd greatly appreciate some helping understanding the problem above.I do understand the first part of the published solution that states that there are 3 paths from point A to point C, but I do not understand how one could find out that there are 15 paths from point C to point B.

Thanks for any help! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

It takes six steps to go from $C$ to $B$, of which two must be up.  There are ${6 \choose 2}=15$ ways to choose which two are up.

Answer (score 0):

a path from $C$ to $B$ can be described as a word with 4 letters $R$ (right) and 2 letters $U$ (up).   for example,

$$RRURRU$$

describes the path of moving twice to the right, then up, then twice to the right, then up.

the amount of such words is $6C2=\frac{6\cdot5}{2}=15$, because constructing such a word is equivalent to choosing which two of the 6 letters would be $U$.